# Can Objects of user defined classes in Java be created on Stack and not dynamically on Heap like they can be in C++?

Tags: java

```
Class A {
  // blah blah
}
```

Now, whenever we need to create an instance of this class, we do:

```
A a = new A();
```

In c++ there are two ways:

```
1. A a(10); // Created on Stack. Assume that the constructor takes an int argument 
2. A a = new A(); // Created on Heap
```

How do you create user defined Java objects on stack?

Comment: Hmmm...you're right. How about A a(5); Assume that the constructor takes an int parameter. Now it's on stack.

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't. All method-local primitive types and references are put on the stack, all objects are put in the heap. No ifs and buts about it.

One reason I can think why they did is that it removes one commonly made error: you pass the stack-based object to a method that stores a reference to that object. Then the object goes out of scope, is removed from the stack, and the reference points to something undefined. Next when you want to access the "object" through the reference, you're in a world of hurt since the object is no longer there - and nobody knows what is.

Comment: I see. That clears the confusion. Thanks. So, just to be clear again, in Java, it is impossible to create user user defined class objects on Stack and variables of primitive data types on Heap, right?

Comment: Java only stores primitives on the stack. This keeps the stack small and helps keeping individual stack frames small, thus allowing more nested calls.
Objects are created on the heap, and only references (which in turn are primitives) are passed around on the stack.

So if you create an object, it is put on the heap, with all the variables that belong to it, so that it can persist after the function call returns.